# Hive. Столбец, содержащий одно значение разных типов структур

Tags: hive

Есть пять разных типов структур:

```
1(string, string), 2(string, string, int), 3(string, float, float, float, string), 4(string, string, string), 5(string, string, long, int, string)
```

В таблице, которую нужно создать, в одном столбце нужно хранить структуру, которой может быть одна из вышеперечисленных. Можно ли в hive создать такую таблицу? И если можно, то как будет выглядеть запрос create table для нее?